# Scramble a PHP string

Tags: php

I want to create Unique ID for my site users in this format

> pubID-john_34032

So I want to do this using the email string.

I have this pseudo code (but I want it faster and more logical if that makes sense)

How do I write my Pseudo code as PHP?

```
<?php
$var e(mysqlescape(get(emailform));
$var r(rand(3,34);
$var ex=(pubID-);
$var e=(replace(@/.); //users may enter 1@site.com so replace the at and .
$var e(first4strTo(e)); // get first four letters, example 1sit 
$var e(e)+r(); // e is now 1site-1547
$var printStr e+ex //join the 1site-1547 with pubID- and done
?>
```

Comment: How do I write my Pseudo code as PHP.

Comment: Do you know any PHP? What is `get`, `e`, `r` supposed to do?

Comment: It is Pseudo code - yes I know PHP - not a pro. Get is short for $_GET and e is a $e and r is $r - that is how we write strings in some pseudo code at work.

Comment: your code doesn't look like a pseudocode neither

Comment: And what does `e=` mean then, or `e(e)+r()`? The problem with psoude-code is that there is no standard. How do you expect anyone to understand that `e(...)` is a variable assignment and not a function call? If you use pseudo-code and diverge from "traditional" syntax, you have to explain its meaning. Otherwise no one will understand. You could at least write PHP-syntax related pseudo-code.

Comment: OK, sorry man, will do in future. Agree completely with that.

Comment: Deleting this would be unfair to the people who took their time to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to remove the `@` and `.` characters then use [`uniqid()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) to generate a unique identifier. Finally, concatenate them all together.

```
$email = 'user@gmail.com';
$str = 'pubID-' . str_replace(array('@', '.'), '', $email) . '_' . uniqid();
echo $str;
```

Answer (score 3):

Unique Id in PHP there is  [uniqid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php). You can append that to whatever string. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: OK, so how do I get the first characters? And strip the @ (with replace) I am guessing? I wanted a quick snippet for my solution rather than my 4 year old method of string(function) new line same string(function) etc

Comment: what you can do is take email username ie with out site name and append uniqid (which i think is more cleaner tha random numbers) to it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation points to respond on Emmanuel N's answer.

Here's how to use uniqid and just grab the first part of the email address.

```
uniqid(substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@')) . '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see your reasoning here.  Why: pubID-john_34032

Couldn't you use the the user's name and append an auto incrementing id generated by your database?  Something like:

calvinfroedge_23923

Then all you have to do is replace non whitelisted characters in the names and put an underscore between the name and the id.

Comment: My database starts with 3, 4 and does not have so many rows. Aside from this, my reasoning is logical and for this purpose needed; my reasoning therefore is my own. Appreciate the comments.